# AWS CloudFormation: How to refer a role defined in another stack inside AWS::IAM::Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

**Cloudformation Stack 1:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
    c311c237-d7a4-4fac-a838-8a5a37a4b083:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 127
        'y': 160
      z: 0
Resources:
  ECSRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ecs-service
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ec2:AttachNetworkInterface'
                  - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
                  - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission'
                  - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'
                  - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission'
                  - 'ec2:Describe*'
                  - 'ec2:DetachNetworkInterface'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets'
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  ECSTaskRoleId:
    Description: ECSRoleId
    Value: !GetAtt
      - ECSRole
      - RoleId
    Export:
      Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', ECSTaskRoleId ] ]
  ECSTaskRoleIdECSRole:
    Description: The ARN of the ECS role
    Value: !GetAtt 'ECSRole.Arn'
    Export:
      Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'ECSRole' ] ]

**
```

Stack 2:**

```
Resources:
  SNSRWPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      Role :
        - Fn::ImportValue: 'testk2:ECSTaskRoleId'
      PolicyName: test-snspolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'sns:Publish'
              - 'kms:Decrypt'
              - 'kms:GenerateDataKey'
     
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: c5c7c890-30c7-470d-9233-57b8bd630856
```

I am getting below error

The role with name AROA3RRAFXNEDPVQKOLIW cannot be found. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchEntity; Request ID: d5ad937f-94c3-458e-a803-0c37258e05f1; Proxy: null)

How can I import IAM::Role to attach a policy in another stack?
Beginner in CloudFormation :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you exporting the role id? Export and import the role name instead.

Comment: @Luke ***obviously*** a role named `AROA3RRAFXNEDPVQKOLIW` does not exist because that is the *id* of the role, not the name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy' property Roles expects a Role **name** and **not role ID**.

CloudFormation is quite sensitive to names vs ID. So always ensure that you mention correct property.

```
Outputs:
  ECSTaskRole:
    Description: The ECSRole name
    Value: !Ref ECSRole
```

So while exporting it will export the name and importValue will take the name properly.

[AWS::IAM::Policy Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-roles)